# Is there a way to make an element spin around without a variable telling how far it has already turned?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I have an experimental website that plays music, and I want the forward and backward buttons to spin when you click them. But, I also don't want to have 2 variables to be how far they have turned, or a function to get how far they have turned from the CSS transform property. They have a transition, for hover effects. I have tried

```
    backward.classList.add("notrans");
    backward.style.transform = "rotateZ(0deg)";
    backward.classList.remove("notrans");
    backward.style.transform = "rotateZ(-360deg)";
```

and some closely related things, and also have a setTimeout to reset it afterwards, which it too long for a post.

Comment: how beautiful you say "there is". But where it is ? :) Please share us.

Answer (score 0):

**Animate** is what you are searching for.
*This should be a working example: (Tested in FF and Chrome)*

```js
/* THIS IS A JAVASCRIPT CLASS THAT ADDS AND
REMOVES THE CSS CLASS FROM YOUR ELEMENT
USING THE ELEMENT'S ID VALUE TO REFERENCE. */

function startStop(strstp) {
  var infinite = document.getElementById("imSpinning");
  var once = document.getElementById("imSpinningOnce");
  
  if(strstp == 1)
  {
    infinite.classList.add("spin");
    once.classList.add("spinOnce");
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      once.classList.remove("spinOnce");
    },1000); 
  }
  else
  {
    infinite.classList.remove("spin");
    once.classList.remove("spinOnce");
  }
}
```

```css
/* THIS IS THE CSS CLASS THAT CREATES INFINITE ROTATION */

.spin {
    -webkit-animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }



/* THIS IS THE CSS CLASS THAT ROTATES ONCE */

.spinOnce {
    -webkit-animation:spin 1s linear;
    -moz-animation:spin 1s linear;
    animation:spin 1s linear;
}
@-moz-keyframes spinOnce { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spinOnce { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spinOnce { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

```html
<div style="width: 100px; height: 30px; background-color: green; color: white; margin: 20px; text-align: center; cursor: pointer;" onclick="startStop(1)">
GO
</div>

<div style="width: 100px; height: 30px; background-color: red; color: white; margin: 20px; text-align: center; cursor: pointer;" onclick="startStop(0)">
STOP
</div>

<!-- ELEMENT TO ROTATE INFINITLY WITH "spin" CLASS -->
<div id="imSpinning" class="spin" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 30px; height: 140px; width: 140px; background-image: url(https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/thehoth/seo/256/seo-web-code-icon.png); background-size: 100% 100%; background-position: center center; border-radius: 50%; overflow: hidden;"></div>


<!-- ELEMENT TO ROTATE ONCE WITH "spin" CLASS -->
<div id="imSpinningOnce" class="spinOnce" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 200px; height: 140px; width: 140px; background-image: url(https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/thehoth/seo/256/seo-web-code-icon.png); background-size: 100% 100%; background-position: center center; border-radius: 50%; overflow: hidden;"></div>
```

Simply copy the CSS class above to the style section/sheet of your page and modify it as needed. Ensure you reference the class in your html element.

Also I edited in a small JavaScript class that add/removes the ***spin*** class from the DIV element if it helps you in starting and stopping the animation.

Hope this helps, and best of luck!

Comment: thank you, but I was looking for an answer that makes it spin one, after the button is bressed, with no start or stop button. =D

Comment: That's what I included an example that spins once. The "GO" button is what you asked for. Perhaps you didn't wait for the animation to end or you need it speeded up? I changed it to 1 second. You can click go as many times as you would like. It will start again.